# Multiple combination of modifiers for one key in RegisterHotkey C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm making a windows form application and I need to detect if a key is pressed (Globally), so I ended up with using hotkeys and everything works fine. I registered key 'V' as the hotkey and when I press it my app can detect it. But the problem is when I press V while I'm holding 'Shift' or 'Control' , my app won't detect the key press anymore.
I found a way to also register modifier keys, but I can only register one combination , and if I register multiple combinations like :"V" ,"Control + V" ,and "Shift + V" , only the last one works but I want my app to detect 'V' in any combination.
Here is the code I use for Registering hotkeys(Found on the internet)

```
 private class KeyHandler
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vk);

        private readonly int _key;
        private readonly IntPtr _hWnd;
        private readonly int _id;
        private readonly int _modifier;

        public KeyHandler(Keys key, KeyModifiers modifier, Form form)
        {
            _key = (int)key;
            _modifier = (int)modifier;
            _hWnd = form.Handle;
            _id = GetHashCode();
        }

        public sealed override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return _key ^ _hWnd.ToInt32();
        }

        public void Register()
        {
            RegisterHotKey(_hWnd, _id, _modifier, _key);
        }
    }

    public enum KeyModifiers : int
    {
        None = 0,
        Alt = 1,
        Control = 2,
        Shift = 4,
        Win = 8
    }
    private static int WM_HOTKEY = 0x0312;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_HOTKEY)
        {
            HandleHotkey();
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
    
    //On Press
    private void HandleHotkey()
    {
        
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Register hotkey
        new KeyHandler(Keys.V, 0, this).Register();
    }
```

Is there any way to detect a key press globally even if the key is pressed with modifiers?

Comment: RegisterHotKey() makes very little sense with these requirements, google "c# low level keyboard hook" to get ahead.

Comment: Thank you for your hint, It helped me a lot and I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant)'s comment, I found this source code on Github which allows you to capture keyboard events.

https://github.com/rvknth043/Global-Low-Level-Key-Board-And-Mouse-Hook